# Email sending as background process using CakeResque

Tags: php, email, backgroundworker, background-process, cakephp-2.4

**MailShell.php**

```
<?php

App::uses('AppShell', 'Console/Command');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class MailShell extends AppShell
{

    public function sendMail() {
        $Email = new CakeEmail();
        $Email->from(array('admin@localhost' => 'My Site'));
        $Email->to($this->args[1]);
        $Email->subject($this->args[3]);
        $Email->send($this->args[2]);
    }
}
```

**TestController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class TestController extends AppController {

    public function index(){
        CakeResque::enqueue('default','CakeResque.Mail', array('sendMail','test@gmail.com','Test Email','Hi this it test email.'));
    }
}
```

When I am open URL

```
http://localhost/test/index
```

Jobs are enqueued properly in default queue see

[image]

and when I start workers and after stats looks like below

[image]

For every Job It increases **Processed Jobs by 1** and **Failed Jobs by 2** and email is not send

What is real issue ? Is issue with email sending procedure ? Is issue with CakeResque?

Any Help appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While enqueuing jobs from TestController use

```
CakeResque::enqueue('default',
                    'CakeResque.MailShell',   //difference is here
                     array('sendMail',
                           'test@gmail.com',
                           'Test Email',
                           'Hi this it test email.'));
```

instead of

```
CakeResque::enqueue('default',
                    'CakeResque.Mail',                                   
                     array('sendMail',
                          'test@gmail.com',
                          'Test Email',
                          'Hi this it test email.'));
```

Comment: TestController doesn't have to find the MailShell, since it never uses it. Issue is the way you reference the Job class when queueing the queue, use `CakeResque.MailShell` instead of `CakeResque.Mail` when referencing the queue in `CakeResque::enqueue`

Comment: @Kamisama,Thank you for response,Code is working now but still didn't got why it increase failed job though the job was proceed successfully and your tutorial is nice.

Comment: You should open a ticket on github, with everything needed to reproduce the issue